# Responsive height, based by background size

Tags: css, image-resizing

I need my background image to be responsive. I have used `background-size: contain` and that seems to work fine but I need the height of my div to be responsive as well.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.bg {
  background: red url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg') no-repeat center top;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

For now the height is 600px and based on the width of the screen, you will see a red background, which should not be the case.

I have tried `background: cover`, but it will scale the image. It should be 100% of the div but it should not be cut.

How can I fix this?

https://jsfiddle.net/mt386Ln0/

Comment: try `height: auto;`

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Since 960 x 720 is  a `4:3` ratio of `ratioWidth:ratioHeight`. `width = knownHeight*ratioWidth/ratioHeight` `height = knownWidth*ratioHeight/ratioWidth`. So `600*4/3 = 800`

Comment: Oops, I realized that is `960:628`. So `600*960/628 = 917.19745222929936305732484076433`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy solution without using JavaScript. Just add `<svg>` with specific ratio inside a container.

You must use image dimensions as viewBox `<svg viewBox="0 0 960 628"></svg>`

Example:

```css
div{
  background-image:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
svg{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  visibility:hidden;
}


.demo-1{width:100%}
.demo-2{width:40%}
```

```html
<div class="demo-1">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 960 628"></svg>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="demo-2">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 960 628"></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the ratio of the image you can consider the padding trick:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.bg {
  background: red url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg') center/100%;
}

.bg:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: calc((628/960) * 100%); /* OR 65.42% */
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `background-size: contain`, I used `background-size: auto`, which seems to work the way you want it to. Furthermore, I added some javascript to help with the resizing.

```js
window.resize = function() {
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var b = document.getElementById("b");
a.style.width = "100%";
b.backgroundSize = "auto";
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.bg {
  background: red url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/06/30/09/31/background-image-3507320_960_720.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: auto;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id = "a">
  <div class="bg" id = "b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that as well but `cover` will scale the image. I need the image to be full size.

Comment: so you don't want the image to cover the entire div?

Comment: It should be 100% of the div but it should not be cut.

Comment: Unfortunately not, since the background image is not responsive now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
background-size: cover
```

this will allow the background to always cover the DIV - you might need to tweek the -

```
background-position: xxxxx
```

as sometimes the screen size your viewing the image on will mean setting a `@meda` query to get it right for each different deceive (i.e. mobile or desktop)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: This will not work since `background-position` nor `background-size` don't make `height` proportional to `width`.